# How to read Delve contact info / profile from Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, delve

I've set my mobile via Delve edit profile but when I access https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me I still see the mobile defined in AD.  How do I obtain the contact info I set via Delve?

My account is backed by an AD account and must be configured to sync w/ Azure AD (don't know the exact details).  Does that come into play here?

[image: delve profile screenshot]

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [
        "610-555-1111"
    ],
    "displayName": "Michael DePouw",
    "givenName": "Michael",
    "jobTitle": "Dev",
    "mail": "mdepouw@blah.com",
    "mobilePhone": "407-555-3333",
    "officeLocation": "DET",
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "DePouw",
    "userPrincipalName": "mdepouw@blah.com",
    "id": "24cb7258-0703-4c76-92b6-bc9323fb94ab"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for extracting `Skills` from the `Delve` using Microsoft Graph API and just found [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/263148/expertise-from-delve-via-graph-api).

> This query will return your Skills and Expertise (listed as
> 'responsibilities' - it's a string collection, same as 'skills')
>
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=displayName,skills,responsibilities

This served my purpose. However, when I tried to access `contacts` using both `v1.0` and `beta`, both showed me `Forbidden - 403` which means I don't have permission to access this.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts
```

Perhaps you can ask your organization for permission.

**Update**
You can only get a business phone but not a personal cell phone number. Try this:

```
# for yourself
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?$select=businessPhones

# for other users
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/USERID?$select=displayName,businessPhones
```